# Android java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException: -1

Tags: android

The following code is used to backup contacts  as vcf file.
This works fine on devices below api 23 but in higher api's i get java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException: -1. any idea why?
Thanks

here is the complete code and error log

```
 private void getVcardString() throws IOException {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //ProgressBar pro = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.pb);
            try {


            // ProgressBar pro = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.pb1);
            vCard = new ArrayList<String>();  // Its global....
            cursor = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, ContactsContract.Contacts.IN_VISIBLE_GROUP + "=1",
                    null, null, null);
            if (cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0) {
                int i;
                String storage_path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + File.separator + vfile;
                FileOutputStream mFileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(storage_path, false);
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                for (i = 0; i < cursor.getCount(); i++) {

                    get(cursor);
                    Log.d("TAG", "Contact " + (i + 1) + "VcF String is" + vCard.get(i));
                    cursor.moveToNext();

                    mFileOutputStream.write(vCard.get(i).toString().getBytes());
                }
                mFileOutputStream.close();
                cursor.close();
                new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        tx.setText("");
                        pro.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        btn3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        tx1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.backupdone, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                        toast.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 0, 90);
                        toast.show();

                    }
                });




            } else {
                Log.d("TAG", "No Contacts in Your Phone");
            }
        }catch ( Exception e){
             e.printStackTrace();
            }}

        private void get(Cursor cursor2) {
            String lookupKey = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY));
            Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_VCARD_URI, lookupKey);
            AssetFileDescriptor fd;
            try {
                fd = getContentResolver().openAssetFileDescriptor(uri, "r");

                FileInputStream fis = fd.createInputStream();
                byte[] buf = new byte[(int) fd.getDeclaredLength()];
                fis.read(buf);
                String vcardstring = new String(buf);
                vCard.add(vcardstring);

            } catch (Exception e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    });
```

Error Log

```
07-03 00:20:55.796 9500-10477/com.HEbackup W/System.err: 
java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException: -1
07-03 00:20:55.796 9500-10477/com.HEbackup W/System.err:     at 
app.HEbackup.cbackup$1.get(cbackup.java:212)
07-03 00:20:55.796 9500-10477/com.HEbackup W/System.err:     at 
app.HEbackup.cbackup$1.getVcardString(cbackup.java:172)
07-03 00:20:55.796 9500-10477/com.HEbackup W/System.err:     at 
app.HEbackup.cbackup$1.access$000(cbackup.java:120)
07-03 00:20:55.797 9500-10477/com.HEbackup W/System.err:     at 
app.HEbackup.cbackup$1$1.run(cbackup.java:144)
07-03 00:20:55.797 9500-10477/com.HEbackup W/System.err:     at 
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
```

Answer (score 2):

`fd.getDeclaredLength()` returns `-1`, which you try to use to create an array. Since an array with a negative length cannot exist you get a `NegativeArraySizeException`.

Since it seems like the specified asset does not have a predefined length using a `BufferedReader` (and an `InputStreamReader`) to handle reading the contents and the conversion to a `String` would be the correct solution.

Comment: forgive me but what should i convert to string?

Answer (score 0):

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fd.getFileDescriptor());
    byte[] buf = new byte[fis.available()];
    fis.read(buf);
    String vcardstring = new String(buf);
    vCard.add(vcardstring);
```

Comment: Please edit your answer to describe what exactly is different from the asker's version. Code-only answers are poor practice.